# StreamSocket : datareader.LoadAsync waits infinte even when data is avaialbe

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I have the following code in my Windows phone 8 app.

```
//connection code, done during app start
socket = new StreamSocket();
await socket.ConnectAsync(serverHostName, serviceName);
dataReader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
dataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
dataWriter = new DataWriter(socket.OutputStream);
```

After the connection is established, I have another thread which checks for incoming network packets

```
await dataReader.LoadAsync(2048);
dataReader.ReadBytes(buffer);
----------
```

Workflow is as follows

- Phone connects to server using socket.ConnectAsync
- Server responds with initial message (Phone receives this properly in dataReader.LoadAsync function)
- Phone now sends the 'business specific' request
- Server now replies with 'business specific' response (**Problem lies here. Phone doesn't receive the reply from server at some of the times).**

There is no scenario difference between working state' and 'non working state'.

So I tried to debug this. I **put a breakpoint for dataReader.LoadAsync and saw that execution waits infinitely at the call.**

To make sure that the server is sending data properly, I ran the app in Windows phone emulator and ran the **WireShark network analyzer** in the PC. I could see that packets are being received for the IP Address of the phone.

Anyone has any hints on why the dataReader.LoadAsync function call doesn't return at all, when there is data ready to be read in the socket?

Comment: It will wait until 2048 bytes are available. Not less.

Comment: i have set InputStreamOption as Partial which means, LoadAsync will return as soon as the first byte is available.

Comment: My bad, I was using a tiny smartphone, now I see it.

Comment: How big is the first buffer you passed to ReadBytes? Are you sure there is no more dataReader.unconsumedBufferLength available?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the UnconsumbedBufferLength is zero. I do consume all the read bytes in the first call using the ReadBytes function. To keep the code simple & clear, I couldn't include all the code here.

Comment: I had this exact same problem, but I was using the the SerialDevice class' stream with my DataReader. I'm thinking more and more that this is either a bug or an improper documentation of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem. It is especially bad for Bluetooth RFCOMM SPP serial port devices, because the underlying Rfcomm-object does not provide capabilities for setting ReadTimeout values.
Edit: The InputStreamOptions.Partial option seems to be working UWP Win10 platform, but it is only useful when you are already know much data you are expecting. Otherwise it will wait indefinitely on the last call.

I almost gave up, when I found in references below these lines to solve the problem by using a *CancellationTokenSource*

```
//connect your Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService 
// see the Bluetooth chat example
[...]
StreamSocket streamSocket      = new StreamSocket();  
await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(...); //connect to Bluetooth device

DataReader dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream); // to read from the stream

try
 {
    var timeoutSource   = new CancellationTokenSource(1000); // 1000 ms
    uint numberBytesToRead = 256;
    var data    = await dataReader.LoadAsync(numberBytesToRead).AsTask(timeoutSource.Token);
 }
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
  // we will get here, and everything looks fine, but the problem is:
  // The underlying streamSocket is also closed!
  // we can not re-use the streamSocket. Any more calls to LoadAsync results in exceptions (something about the object being not assigned...)
  // we need to do a full   await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(...)  again, but that takes ~3 seconds.
}
```

So this method is only a brute-force, last-resort attempt at a time-out.

The method from @mayu works very good (serialDevice.ReadTimeout), but only on devices of class Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.Serial​Device, but **not** on 
Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm.RfcommDeviceService. I don't know how the situation is for TCP/IP sockets.

In short, is there any usable time-out for RFCOMM SPP Bluetooth connections?
Or any method to know ahead of time if .LoadAsync(1) will block, because no new data is available?

This fellow over at MSDN has the exact same problem, but MS don't know an answer either: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71ea17d4-ca16-43c2-ab43-02d5301def3f/chow-to-set-timeout-on-streamsocketreadasync?forum=wpdevelop

References:

[In UWP StreamSocket, can I read data with timeout and leave the connection open if timeout elapses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42577355/in-uwp-streamsocket-can-i-read-data-with-timeout-and-leave-the-connection-open)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8a5c4fdc-28d6-4a22-8df6-bc519efeaa4d/how-to-control-the-timeout-for-reading-from-streamsocket?forum=winappswithcsharp

[DataReader of SocketStream for UWP App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015649/datareader-of-socketstream-for-uwp-app)

Answer (score 2):

"According to documentation when using InputStreamOptions.Partial, you should use UnconsummedBufferLength instead of an hardcoded value"

That sample seems to be broken.

"await reader.LoadAsync(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);" is equivalent to

await reader.LoadAsync(0); and then it's not possible to read any data, since you have no buffer to read from.

I'm testing this now and it seems like "reader.InputStreamOptions = Partial;" has no effect at all. My only workaround is to lower the read timeout.

Comment: This description is consistent with what I see using it.  Once the unconsumed buffer is 0 it never returns data.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation when using InputStreamOptions.Partial, you should use UnconsummedBufferLength instead of an hardcoded value :

```
 DataReader reader = new DataReader(clientSocket.InputStream);
 // Set inputstream options so that we don't have to know the data size
 reader.InputStreamOptions = Partial;
 await reader.LoadAsync(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
```

[Sample is there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150599.aspx)

Comment: according to MSDN [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.unconsumedbufferlength , UnconsumedBufferLength indicates the number of bytes remaining in the buffer. So in my case, it should be the number of bytes loaded from the network socket using LoadAsync Api, but not yet read by the ReadBytes Api. So if I have already consumed all the loaded bytes using ReadBytes function, value would be zero which eventually will lead to reader.LoadAsync(0);

Comment: Do you have a link to MSDN **documentation** which mentions the same? IMHO, the MSDN ***sample*** given in the link, might not work. Because, reader.UnconsumedBufferLength will be zero before the fist call to reader.LoadAsync is made. Hence nothing will be read.

Comment: If your take the InputStreamOptions documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.inputstreamoptions.aspx it states that with partial the asynchronous read operation completes when one or more bytes are available (not zero). I have not tested this scenario myself.

Comment: I think the sample might work because it writes to the socket just before and synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using Windows Remote Arduino library and SerialUSB stream. I had to change this library and call LoadAsync(1) instead of original LoadAsync(100). Now the code is working  fine.

see: https://github.com/ms-iot/remote-wiring/issues/111

Answer (score 0):

For serial devices you need to set

`device.ReadTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);`

for the LoadAsync to return before the buffer is full.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get round not knowing the size of the data before reading was to read one byte at a time until I got a timeout.  Feels horrid, but works.  Is there a better way yet?

```
private async Task ReadData(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    DataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    uint data = 0;

    uint bufferLength = DataReaderObject.UnconsumedBufferLength;
    var timeoutSource = new CancellationTokenSource(100); // 100 ms

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            data = await DataReaderObject.LoadAsync(1).AsTask(timeoutSource.Token);
            if (data > 0)
            {
                String temp = DataReaderObject.ReadString(data);
                TemperatureValue.Text += temp.Trim();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        ;
    }
}
```