# DataReader of SocketStream for UWP App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I've seen a few questions similar to this, but so far I've not seen an actual solution that works for the UWP platform.

I'm connecting to some UPnP devices on the network, which send JSON back over port 1255. I have the initial connection working and the send request that tells the devices to send me some info.

```
StreamSocket socket;
using (socket = new StreamSocket())
{
    hostName = new HostName("192.168.0.nnn");
    await socket.ConnectAsync(hostName, "1255");
    //Code that does the request for info
    await this.read();
}

public async Task<String> read()
{
    string runStr = "";
    uint inBufferCnt = 0;

    using (reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream))
    {
        reader.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead;
        reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        reader.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

        inBufferCnt = await reader.LoadAsync(256); //InBuffer is always 256, 
            //even if there is more data waiting. If I put a task.delay in it will always return 256

        while (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength > 0)
        {
            var iRead = reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
            runStr = runStr + iRead;
            inBufferCnt = await reader.LoadAsync(64); //always hangs here. 
                //Even if I reduce to 1, it will sit waiting for new data
        }
...
```

Everything is working fine, up till the last LoadAsync. While there is data in the stream, then as long as it's less than 64 bytes then it'll spin back around the While loop. If there is less than this tho, then it just sits there waiting for more data. So there could be 50 bytes sat in the buffer that I can't get hold of. In the above the inBufferCnt is always the exact size of the value passed to LoadAsync.

I've been trying various things, such as adding a timeout, but I can't access anything of use after the exception is triggered, so I still don't know how much data is in the stream.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(5000);
...
inBufferCnt = await reader.LoadAsync(64).AsTask(cts.Token);
```

I have no idea how much data I will get back from the device, I have no control whatsoever over the device communication (Other than to request info). I think I've read half of the web while looking for a solution, but I can't find anything that relates directly to this specific issue.

So the main question is "How are you supposed to read from the socket stream and then when there is no more data (at this time), just return what is sitting in the current stream. There could be any size left in the buffer waiting to be read.

Help...

Answer (score 0):

> I have no idea how much data I will get back from the device, I have no control whatsoever over the device communication (Other than to request info).
>   So the main question is "How are you supposed to read from the socket stream and then when there is no more data (at this time), just return what is sitting in the current stream. There could be any size left in the buffer waiting to be read.

According to your description, I have found a solution for you:

First, set the [read options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.streams.inputstreamoptions.aspx) for the input stream to **Partial**.

```
reader.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.Partial;
```

By doing this, the asynchronous read operation **completes** when one or more bytes is available. So the asynchronous read operation sits and waits for new data **only** when there is **no** any bytes is available, then you can **add a timeout** to handle this situation as you have mentioned above.

```
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
cts.CancelAfter(5000);
...
inBufferCnt = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeToReadEachTime).AsTask(cts.Token);
```

Following is the sample code I’ve verified:

```
public async Task<String> read()
{
    string runStr = "";
    uint inBufferCnt = 0;
    //size of bytes to load each time.
    uint sizeToReadEachTime = 256;
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //set timeout here.
    cts.CancelAfter(5000);

    using (reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream))
    {
        //set the read options for the input stream to Partial.
        reader.InputStreamOptions = Windows.Storage.Streams.InputStreamOptions.Partial;
        reader.UnicodeEncoding = Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
        reader.ByteOrder = Windows.Storage.Streams.ByteOrder.LittleEndian;

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                //add a timeout for the asynchronous load operation.
                inBufferCnt = await reader.LoadAsync(sizeToReadEachTime).AsTask(cts.Token);
                runStr += reader.ReadString(inBufferCnt);
            }
            catch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException)
            {
                //load operation will get timeout only when there is no data available.
                cts.Dispose();
                break;
            }
        }

        reader.DetachStream();
    }
    return runStr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the issue I get with this approach is that if there was data in the stream, but not enough to fill the entire sizeToReadEachTime, then when the exception occurs, you still can't get at the data without decreasing the variable to an even lower number. I've managed to get the data by reducing the value to 1, and then doing more evaluation on the data, then combined with the exception timeout I know I have all of the data. But this seems like a really crap way of doing it. IMO the uint returned by LoadAsync should return the size of what's actually in the buffer

Comment: You are welcome:) And I know exactly what your issue is. So I said you need to set **read option** for the input stream to **Partial** at the beginning of my answer.  By doing that, the uint returned by LoadAsync will return the size of what's actually in the buffer even when there was data in the stream but not enough to fill the entire sizeToReadEachTime. All data will be gotten before the the exception occurs. The exception occurs only when there is no any data in the stream. So you don't need to reduce the value to an even lower number or to 1 in my solution above.

Comment: I had used the Partial option originally, and I think I got most of the code snippet from here: http://donatas.xyz/streamsocket-tcpip-client.html. But I found that the uint was always the size of the value you pass to it, and it always hung on the LoadAsync when there was less data available. I'll give it a try again later in the week, when I'm back at my dev workstation. I don't think I tried the cancellation as well as partial, so I'll be upset if that works ;)

Comment: Does not work, and contains syntax errors. "reader" and "socket" not declared. After first call to reader.LoadAsync jumps into exception